# Getting form from Website A in Website B with AJAX request and apply css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, cross-domain

I have a Website A with a form. I want to show the form from Website A in Website B. The Websites are on different Domains, but I have access to both. Is it possible to get the form from A on B with a Ajax request?

The Css on Website B  should style the form coming from A and I should be able to fill in the form and it should send the data to the same place, as if I would have filled the form on page A.

I know that it is possible to get the content through AJAX request with JQL, but does the submit function still works?

Comment: _“Is it possible”_ – yes, if you implement CORS. _“but does the submit function still works?”_ – just a normal form submit? That will work without any problems, as long as the `action` of the form contains an absolute URL. (If it was only a relative URL, the browser would resolve it against domain B.)

Comment: okay thanks, and the css of the form is the same like the css on A or B or is there no css applied?

Comment: Depends. Inline styling would of course be applied the same way - but any formatting coming from an external stylesheet or a style element would of course require that you load and embed those as well. And the styles of A and B will “mix” in that case, so you need to be careful to write your rules in a way that they affect the form only, and not the other elements that are already on the B page.

Comment: Let's say i got a stylsheet for Page B and I want to adjust css of the form with this stylesheet and not any css from A. Does this work?

Comment: Once you inserted the form into the document, the stylesheet applies to it like it would to any other element that was part of the document to begin with.